# TFS Build: An error occurred while processing your request. - SQL Server Error: 2601

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I get the following error when trying to do a TFS build:

[image: Error]

The thing is that it is working for other branches and I did a copy of the branch, and it worked properly, so it has something to do with that specific branch.

I also deleted the files from the /Cache/ TFS folder.

 Do you have any idea how I can properly debug this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Which version of VS are you using? If you work on this branch on your build agent machine, could you reproduce this issue?

Comment: The version of SQL Server or Visual Studio is not very relevant because it is working on other branches or when using a copy of the branch. The build is done using TFS Build.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Microsoft in the TFS group.  Your symptoms could be a result of data corruption in TFVC.  I suggest you file a support ticket with Microsoft.  Here are some links for that.  The first is for on-premises TFS and the second is for our cloud service.

https://www.visualstudio.com/support/support-overview-vs

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs

If you prefer you can contact me directly (wlennon at Microsoft.com) and I can give you a SQL query to run to determine if it's data corruption or not.

Also, you can look in the EventViewer on your SQL Server machine for more details about this error.  Look for a message like this:

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.tbl_LabelEntry' with unique index 'PK_tbl_LabelEntry'